# Android get lat&long from google address

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have implemented `Google Place API` autocomplete functionality for my application like this: https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

No it just makes a `Toast` with that address.

How can I get the `latitude` and `longitude` from the selected address?

Comment: you can use Geocoder class for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method

`public List<Address> getFromLocationName (String locationName, int maxResults)` from Android [Geocoder API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html), pass in the location name and the maximum number of results you would like and you should be good to go.

Eg.

```
 Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    try {
        ArrayList<Address> adresses = (ArrayList<Address>) coder.getFromLocationName("Some Address", 10);
        for(Address add : adresses){
                double longitude = add.getLongitude();
                double latitude = add.getLatitude();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, I've recently created a library in Java for Google Places API.

Autocompletion is as simple as:

```
GooglePlaces client = new GooglePlace("apiKey");
List<Prediction> predictions = client.getPlacePredictions("Empire");
for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
    String description = prediction.getDescription();
    // etc etc
}
```

And getting a latitude-longitude from an address is as simple as.

```
List<Place> places = client.getPlacesByQuery(address, GooglePlaces.MAXIMUM_RESULTS);
for (Place place : places) {
    if (place.getAddress().equals(address)) {
        double lat = place.getLatitude();
        double lng = place.getLongitude();
    }
}
```

https://github.com/windy1/google-places-api-java

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use google maps api to get the lat and long

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=&sensor=false
```

In the above link u have to add the address next to "address=" and u can get the json data with lat and long and some other infos.

Answer (score 0):

Try GeoDataClient. Refer [GeoDataClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataClient) and [Place IDs and details](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details).

```
geoDataClient.getPlaceById(autoCompletePredictionItem.getPlaceId())
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlaceBufferResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlaceBufferResponse> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    PlaceBufferResponse places = task.getResult();
                                    Place myPlace = places.get(0);
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Place found: " + myPlace.getLatLng().toString());
                                    places.release();
                                } else {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Place not found.");
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to updated documents, GeoDAtaClient is deprecated. New way is to use this:

```
// Define a Place ID. val placeId = "INSERT_PLACE_ID_HERE"

// Specify the fields to return. val placeFields = listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME)

// Construct a request object, passing the place ID and fields array. val request = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeId, placeFields)

placesClient.fetchPlace(request)
    .addOnSuccessListener { response: FetchPlaceResponse ->
        val place = response.place
        Log.i(PlaceDetailsActivity.TAG, "Place found: ${place.name}")
    }.addOnFailureListener { exception: Exception ->
        if (exception is ApiException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: ${exception.message}")
            val statusCode = exception.statusCode
            TODO("Handle error with given status code")
        }
    }
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/place-details#maps_places_get_place_by_id-kotlin