# Converting a PlaceID string to LatLng object

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Im trying to convert a placeId String which I stored on a database to LatLng coordinates, I got the id like so: `place.getId()` from a place object and now when I retirived it from the server I would like to convert it back into coordinates or at least a Place object.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you could take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30952608/5382017) on StackOverflow.

Comment: what should I enter in GoogleApiClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the object as

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
```

Then initialise it as

```
 mGoogleApiClient =
            new GoogleApiClient.Builder(...)
            ...
            .build();
```

And pass it to the Places API's function.

```
Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId)
.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {

@Override
  public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
    if (places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
      final Place myPlace = places.get(0);
      LatLng queriedLocation = myPlace.getLatLng();
      Log.v("Latitude is", "" + queriedLocation.latitude);
      Log.v("Longitude is", "" + queriedLocation.longitude);
    }
    places.release();
  }
});
```

And retrieve the coordinates in the callback. (code copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30952608/5382017))