# Implementing Google places autoComplete textfield implementation in jetpack compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, google-places, placeautocompletefragment

Did anyone implement google autocomplete suggestion text field or fragment in a jetpack compose project? If so kindly guide or share code snippets as I'm having difficulty in implementing it.

**Update**

Here is the intent that I'm triggering to open full-screen dialog, but when I start typing within it gets closed, and also I'm unable to figure out what the issue is and need a clue about handling on activity result for reading the result of the predictions within this compose function.

```
    Places.initialize(context, "sa")

    val fields = listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME)

    val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
        AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN,fields).build(context)

        startActivityForResult(context as MainActivity,intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE, Bundle.EMPTY)
```

Comment: What difficulty? Where's your own attempt?

Comment: @JamesZ kindly have a look at the update, and let me know if you can help or suggest anything about the fix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am using the MVVM architecture and this is how I implemented it:

#### GooglePlacesApi

I've created an api for reaching google api named GooglePlacesApi

```
interface GooglePlacesApi {
    @GET("maps/api/place/autocomplete/json")
    suspend fun getPredictions(
        @Query("key") key: String = <GOOGLE_API_KEY>,
        @Query("types") types: String = "address",
        @Query("input") input: String
    ): GooglePredictionsResponse

    companion object{
        const val BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/"
    }
}
```

The @Query("types") field is for specifiying what are you looking for in the query, you can look for establishments etc.
Types can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#types)

#### Models

So I created 3 models for this implementation:

###### GooglePredictionsResponse

The way the response looks if you are doing a GET request with postman is:

[Google Prediction Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3Xno.png)

You can see that we have an object with "predictions" key so this is our first model.

```
data class GooglePredictionsResponse(
    val predictions: ArrayList<GooglePrediction>
)
```

###### GooglePredictionTerm

```
data class GooglePredictionTerm(
    val offset: Int,
    val value: String
)
```

###### GooglePrediction

```
data class GooglePrediction(
    val description: String,
    val terms: List<GooglePredictionTerm>
)
```

I only needed that information, if you need anything else, feel free to modify the models or create your own.

#### GooglePlacesRepository

And finally we create the repository to get the information (I'm using hilt to inject my dependencies, you can ignore those annotations if not using it)

```
@ActivityScoped
class GooglePlacesRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: GooglePlacesApi,
){
    suspend fun getPredictions(input: String): Resource<GooglePredictionsResponse>{
        val response = try {
            api.getPredictions(input = input)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("Rently", "Exception: ${e}")
            return Resource.Error("Failed prediction")
        }

        return Resource.Success(response)
    }
}
```

Here I've used an extra class I've created to handle the response, called Resource

```
sealed class Resource<T>(val data: T? = null, val message: String? = null){
    class Success<T>(data: T): Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String, data:T? = null): Resource<T>(data = data, message = message)
    class Loading<T>(data: T? = null): Resource<T>(data = data)
}
```

#### View Model

Again I'm using hilt so ignore annotations if not using it.

```
@HiltViewModel
class AddApartmentViewModel @Inject constructor(private val googleRepository: GooglePlacesRepository): ViewModel(){

    val isLoading = mutableStateOf(false)
    val predictions = mutableStateOf(ArrayList<GooglePrediction>())
    
    fun getPredictions(address: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            isLoading.value = true
            val response = googleRepository.getPredictions(input = address)
            when(response){
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    predictions.value = response.data?.predictions!!
                }
            }

            isLoading.value = false
        }
    }

    fun onSearchAddressChange(address: String){
        getPredictions(address)
    }
}
```

If you need any further help let me know

- I didn't include UI implementation because I assume it is individual but this is the easier part ;)

Comment: To improve even more, you could create a state holder `data class AddApartmentUiState(val isLoading: Boolean = false, val predictions: ArrayList<GooglePrediction> = arrayListOf())`. On the view model `private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(AddApartmentUiState()); val uiState: StateFlow<AddApartmentUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()`. To change predictions value use: `_uiState.update`

Answer (score 3):

```
@Composable
fun MyComponent() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val intentLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) {
        when (it.resultCode) {
            Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                it.data?.let {
                    val place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(it)
                    Log.i("MAP_ACTIVITY", "Place: ${place.name}, ${place.id}")
                }
            }
            AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR -> {
                it.data?.let {
                    val status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(it)
                    Log.i("MAP_ACTIVITY", "Place: ${place.name}, ${place.id}")
                }
            }
            Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                // The user canceled the operation.
            }
        }
    }

    val launchMapInputOverlay = {
        Places.initialize(context, YOUR_API_KEY)
        val fields = listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME)
        val intent = Autocomplete
            .IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields)
            .build(context)
        intentLauncher.launch(intent)
    }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = launchMapInputOverlay) {
            Text("Select Location")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Just use Google Maps Places API library

```
implementation("com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.1.0")
```

Initialize it in .Application file in onCreate()

```
Places.initialize(applicationContext, "YOUR_API_KEY")
```

Then invoke the function on every textField input

```
val client = Places.createClient(androidContext())

suspend fun getAddressPredictions(
    sessionToken: AutocompleteSessionToken = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance(),
    inputString: String,
    location: LatLng? = null
) = suspendCoroutine<List<AutocompletePrediction>> {

    placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(
            FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                .setOrigin(location)
                // Call either setLocationBias() OR setLocationRestriction().
                // .setLocationBias(bounds)
                // .setLocationRestriction(bounds)
                .setCountries("US")
                .setTypesFilter(listOf(PlaceTypes.ADDRESS))
                .setSessionToken(sessionToken)
                .setQuery(inputString)
                .build()
    ).addOnCompleteListener { completedTask ->
        if (completedTask.exception != null) {
            Log.e(this@GooglePlacesApi.toString(), completedTask.exception?.stackTraceToString().orEmpty())
            it.resume(listOf())
        } else {
            it.resume(completedTask.result.autocompletePredictions)
        }
    }
}
```

Want to get place LatLng? [Here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77263422/15419983)