# Add Place Autocomplete in TextField Kotlin Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, google-places-api, textfield

Does anyone know how I can add Place Autocomplete in a Compose TextField like this?
[image]

I follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete-tutorial) but I dont know how to link that widget with composable TextField.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea on this? I use AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY that creates another separate widget.

Comment: Hi, I know it's a late response, but take a look at this guy's answer, it might be the one you're looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72586090/10966818